# C# resuable library to treat a text file like a database table?

Tags: c#, text-files

I would like to store values in a text file as comma or tab seperated values (it doesn't matter).

I am looking for a reusable library that can manipulate this data in this text file, as if it were a sql table.

I need `select * from...` and `delete from where ID = ......` (ID will be the first column in the text file).

Is there some code plex project that does this kind of thing?

I do not need complex functionality like joining or relationships. I will just have 1 text file, which will become 1 database table.

Comment: http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/

Comment: Guys seriously the first person who posts SQLLite as an answer, gets it accepted, 20 minutes from not having heard about it, to implementation is pretty outstanding (yes that includes creating the db structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

:)

Answer (score 3):

Use **LINQ to CSV**.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx

http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-CSV-using-DynamicObject.aspx

If its not CSV in that case

Let your file hold one record per line. Each record at runtime should be read into a Collection of type Record [assuming Record is custom class representing individual record]. You can do LINQ operations on the collection and write back the collection into file.

Answer (score 2):

Use ODBC. There is a Microsoft Text Driver for csv-Files. I think this would be possible. I don't have tested if you can manipulate via ODBC, but you can test it easily.
For querying you can also use linq.

Comment: Oops I should have said in the question, I don't want to use odbc, because that means extra management and deployment hassles. But thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: @JL: What would you need to deploy if use ODBC? Do you deploy anything when you use Access database files using ODBC?

Comment: @Hermant - this requirement is an after thought, and is used for storing internal stuff to the app, because of this, I don't want to create yet another deployment step. I was thinking of using a dataset and just serializing this to a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) library?  It has the capability of reading and parsing a text file into CLR objects.  Combining that with the power of something like LINQ to Objects, you have the functionality you need.

Comment: Whoops.  The problem of answering questions when you're partly awake and fingers aren't helping.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Instance { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("database.txt");

        var list = lines
                .Select(l =>
                    {
                        var split = l.Split(',');
                        return new Item
                        {
                            ID = int.Parse(split[0]),
                            Type = split[1],
                            Instance = split[2]
                        };
                    });

        Item secondItem = list.Where(item => item.ID == 2).Single();

        List<Item> newList = list.ToList<Item>();
        newList.RemoveAll(item => item.ID == 2);

        //override database.txt with new data from "newList"
    }
}
```

What about data delete. LINQ for query, not for manipulation.
However, List provides a predicate-based RemoveAll that does what you
want:

```
newList.RemoveAll(item => item.ID == 2);
```

Also you can overview more advanced solution ["LINQ to Text or CSV Files"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/Linq2CSV.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to use ODBC. This should not complicate the deployment, the whole configuration can be set in the connection-string so you do not need a DSN.

Together with a `schema.ini` file you can even set column names and data-types, check this [KB article from MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149090).

Answer (score 0):

[sqllite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [linq to text and csv](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/30/linq-to-text-and-linq-to-csv.aspx) :)